# URL contains "&" returns internal server error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, iis-7

http://staging.syncfusion.com/downloads/Support/DirectTrac/88838/Linq2&sql_9d7a1858.zip this is the link returns the internal server error.

Because of "Linq2&sql_9d7a1858.zip" contains & it returns the error. When tried to run it in localhost, i got the exception "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&)" in Application_Error in global.aspx, then the right action will be called and the file got download. I am using .Net 4.0 framework. I tried to put validate input false in webconfig itself and above the action, but both failed.

Can anyone give solution for this?

Thanks,

Karthik

Comment: encoding the & to &amp; ? I'm not sure if & is a legal file character either.

Comment: @kenny You are confusing [xml/html entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) with encoding of URIs - they are unrelated. For URIs, you'd have to use [percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), but that won't fix this problem, as IIS checks the decoded path value.

Answer (score 3):

You could exclude the `&` character from the list of invalid characters (`<`, `>`, `*`, `%`, `:`, `&`, `\`):

```
<httpRuntime 
    requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,:,\" 
/>
```

Comment: This works fine. but because of we are changing requestValidationMode= 2.0 in web config file it will affect all actions in the website. Can i do it for particular action alone?

Comment: Actually it works for me even if I remove the `requestValidationMode="2.0"` attribute. I will update my answer.